# How to modify .innerHTML text?

Tags: javascript, html

So this is what I have in my body tag:

```
<div class="my-block">

    <p id="demo">

    <font size="5">Old text<br><br>

    <b><text onClick="myFunction()">Click here to continue!</text></b></p> 

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New text"; 
    }
    </script>

    </font>
</div>
```

That works in replacing the text like I wanted it to, but the formatting (like text size) changes to default in the .innerHTML and I can't seem to figure out how to get it back. I can make it bold, small, etc., but I want to change the size to 5 like the rest. I tried to put the font face tag in the quotations (and outside the quotations) with "new text":

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<font size="5"> New text </font>";
```

but it didn't work, even though that works with bold and small.

Comment: face="" is looking for a font-type or font-name, like Arial, but you've given it a "5" which is meaningless. If you want to change the size you need to use size="" like you did above.

Comment: i think your inner html is not valid. you can try something like this. `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<span style='font-size: 30px; font-family: sans-serif;'> New text </span>";
`

Comment: Your markup is a mess. The `</p>` and `</font>` are in the wrong order and there is no `<text>` tag in HTML

Comment: For info, not supported any more in HTML5: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp

Comment: skyline: Whoops, yeah I accidentally put face instead of size. I'm kind of a mess.

Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: DO not use font tags...It is an obsolete tag.

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: CSS - Cascading Style Sheets - it provides an abstract way to add visuals to your HTML markup, that way your content and structure (HTML) and visual styles (CSS) are not coupled together. When you use elements and attributes like <font size="">, there's a dependency between your content and visuals. In big projects it becomes rather difficult to modify and maintain.

Comment: Ohhh okay, that makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring your invalid markup for now, your quotes are nested incorrectly (double-quotes in a double-quoted string). Try

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<font size="5">New text</font>';
```

Alternatively, just target the `<font>` tag

```
document.querySelector('#demo > font').innerHTML = "New Text";
```

Comment: Yeah my markup isn't good whoops. I'm really new to this and probably getting ahead of myself. But that worked, thanks so much! I'll figure out how to fix the rest, appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use a css style in the paragraph. "font-size" does the job.

```
<div class="my-block">

<p id="demo" style="font-size:25px";>

Old text<br><br>

<b><text onClick="myFunction()">Click here to continue!</text></b></p> 

<script>
    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New text"; 
}
</script>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your code :

```
<div class="my-block">

    <p id="demo">

        <font size="5">Old text<br><br>

        <b><text onClick="myFunction()">Click here to continue!</text></b></p> 

        <script>
            function myFunction() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New text"; 
        }
        </script>

        </font>
    </div>
```

This is it should be :

```
<div class="my-block">

    <p id="demo">

    <font size="5">Old text<br><br>

    <b><text onClick="myFunction()">Click here to continue!</text></b>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "New text"; 
        // or u can do this too :
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<font size="5"> New text </font>";
    }
    </script>

    </font>
    </p> 
</div>
```

Look at the `<p></p>` tag

But just for your information, `<font></font>` tag is not supported in HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Check your quotes. You can't have "" inside "" without escaping them but you can have "" inside '' vice versa. Also the 'font' tag is deprecated.

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 25px"> New text </font>';
```