# Javascript: Modify InnerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new in JavaScript. I have table that can have one or more rows.

The first thing I do is verify how many rows I want to insert and use the following command to fill the table .

```
$('#optionsTable').html('<tr id="table"><td width="90%" colspan="2" class="cellheader".......></tr>)
```

When I have more than one row, I'm trying to use the `innerHTML` to get the row that was inserted before because I need to modify it. I mean if I have more than one row I don't need to have the second `<td>` tag (or it can be there but without the `<a href></a>` tag) and I need to have the text "Principal" in bold after the text "Tomorrow" in first `<td>`.

The `innerHTML` that I'm getting from the first row is the following:

```
  <tr id="documento1">
    <td width="90%">Tomorrow</td>
    <td width="10%" align="center">&lt;<a href="javascript: removeUnOrg('1');">Remove</a>&gt;</td>
  </tr>
```

I've already check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957815/how-to-modify-innerhtml-text), but it doesn't solve my problem.
Does anyone can help me finding a solution to change the `innerHTML` please?

Comment: try textContent instead innerHTML

Comment: can you show a example with codepen or jsbin? in that way, we can help you more precisely.

Comment: Make one codepen and give us the link, it's impossible to understand your problem like this.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to agree: your question is not understandable. Maybe you could provide the desired result HTML (put together manually). You could read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example